# A working example of the CLI and STI instructions in x86 16-bit assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, x86-16

I would like a practical example of the `cli` and `sti` instructions in x86 16-bit assembly, i.e. an example in code written in this language which allows me to know what these instructions are for by practice and to go further than theory.

I know the documentation says that `cli` disables the interrupt flag and `sti` enables it and the interrupt flag does not affect
not handling non-maskable interrupts (NMI) or software interrupts generated by the `int` instruction.

In the tutorial I follow I have this code:

```
    mov ax, 0x8000
    cli
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0xF000
    sti
```

- My tests make me say that `cli` and `sti` are useless in the example given in the course, after doing several tests I was able to verify that the results will always be the same whether I put `cli` and `sti` or remove these instructions.
- The explanation of the usefulness of `cli` and `sti` by the speakers on the different topics for the example given in the course is purely theoretical. That is to say that you have to put `cli` and `sti` for safety to avoid bugs / crashes. A speaker on discord says there's a one in a million chance that something goes wrong when I initialize the segments and the stack offset.
  Which means he could never verify his theoretical explanation by himself, he just accepts the theory, no curiosity to go further and experiment by itself, impossible to verify by practice since there is a one in millions chance of having a problem.
- On the various documentations/site strictly no other practical example that really demonstrates what `cli` and `sti` does and how it is useful, just copied and pasted the documentation without sample code, i.e. `cli` sets the interrupt flag to 0, and `sti` sets it to 1. When it is disabled hardware interrupts are ignored. Zero example of use, just the theoretical sentence and
  nothing in practice makes it possible to test this kind of thing, there is indeed an example on a French documentation but the example is also useless than the example of the tutorial that I follow to truly understand. That is to say an example which initializes a segment and which puts `cli` and `sti` before and after the line of code, and if we remove `cli` and `sti` the result will be the same no matter what (maybe we have a one in a million chance that a problem will occur if we remove `cli` and `sti`, that's good, it allows me to never check theory in practice).
- Another speaker on discord tells me that he experimented a bit with all this, that he coded in assembly for a while and that in his experience he understands why you have to put `cli` and `sti`, because otherwise it can cause problems so you have to put it and that's all. When I ask him to give me a practical example (which should be right up his alley since he practiced), he does not do it because he is not at home, but on the other hand gives me a theoretical pad again to explain to me how it is useful, so
  obviously we can explain in great detail how useful it is but never demonstrate utility with a practical example in x86 16-bit assembly.

I specify that I am not familiar with the hardware interrupts. I only tested the software interrupts which one can call with `int`.

I'm in kernel mode, I want a practical example that causes the code to have trouble with hardware interrupts, then another example with `cli` and `sti` that can fix the problem.

Comment: Software interrupts are synchronous and they are not even affected by the flag. Also doing a `mov ss` automatically disables interrupts for the next instruction specifically to avoid the problem so you don't have to use a `cli`/`sti` pair.

Comment: Some early 8088/8086 builds didn't do the interrupt lock out after a write to the `ss` register. This is why people put `cli` and `sti` around a two-instruction stack change. If you didn't use `cli` on these early models then a hardware interrupt could occur after you'd changed `ss` but before you changed `sp`, which could easily corrupt data somewhere in your new stack segment. Later processors do not need this in a stack change due to the interrupt lock out of `ss` write instructions mentioned by @Jester. And on a 386+ machine you can use `lss sp` to switch the stack in a single instruction.

Comment: For a better example of what `cli` is needed for, consider changing the int 1Ch vector in the Interrupt Vector Table. If you use an 8086-compatible program this requires two instructions, as there is no instruction to write 32 bits at once to an arbitrary memory location. (Assume you are not calling DOS to do this, or it's on the DOS to do this with a `cli` equivalent.) Int 1Ch is called, by default, with about 18.2 Hz by the ROM-BIOS's int 08h (IRQ #0) handler. If you update the segment of your int 1Ch vector first, without `cli`, and an int 08h occurs, the control flow will crash.

Comment: Note that as a modern computer executes many billion instructions per second, a one in a million chance means it can happen up to 1000 times a second.  Are you sure you want to risk that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course the whole point of `cli/sti` is to manage the handling of hardware interrupts, so you need some understanding of how hardware interrupts work in general.

Here's a brief overview: a hardware device connected to the CPU can trigger a hardware interrupt (in the case of an 8086, by connecting a high voltage to the INTR pin on the CPU chip, and using other pins to signal which interrupt vector should be called).  When this occurs, *if* the interrupt flag is set, then the CPU completes the instruction that is currently executing, then pushes CS, IP and FLAGS onto the stack, and jumps to the address specified in the appropriate entry of the interrupt vector table, which is the low 1024 bytes of memory (0000:0000-0000:0400).  The programmer should have previously set this entry to point to a block of code (interrupt handler) that is to run in response.  The interrupt handler would do whatever is necessary to deal with the hardware interrupt and then execute `IRET` to return to whatever code was interrupted.  Examples of devices causing hardware interrupts would be: key pressed on keyboard, byte arrives on serial port, timer interrupt (MS-DOS sets up the external timer to generate an interrupt at 18.2 Hz, i.e. every 55 ms).

If the interrupt flag is not set, nothing happens, but the interrupt handler will be called when the flag eventually is set again.

---

So, you would clear the interrupt flag whenever you do not want an interrupt to occur.  This would normally be because you are working with some resource that is shared between the current code and the interrupt handler, such that there would be a conflict if the interrupt handler were to run at this moment.

For example, let's consider the timer interrupt.  A simple handler might do nothing but increment a counter, so that the main thread of execution can tell how much time has passed.  (The 8086 didn't have any other built-in clock hardware.)  If a 16-bit counter is enough, you could simply have:

```
ticks DW 0
handler:
    inc word ptr [ticks]
    iret

main_code:
    mov ax, [ticks] ; now ax contains the number of ticks
```

But at 18.2 Hz, we get very close to 65536 ticks per hour (I think that's why the number 18.2 was chosen), so the counter will overflow about every hour.  That is not good if you need to keep track of time intervals longer than that, so we should use a 32-bit counter instead.  Since x86-16 has no 32-bit arithmetic instructions, we have to use an `ADD/ADC` pair.  Our code could look like:

```
ticks DD 0
handler:
    add word ptr [ticks], 1
    adc word ptr [ticks+2], 0
    iret

main_code:
    mov ax, [ticks]
    ;;; BUG what if interrupt occurs here ???
    mov dx, [ticks+2]
    ; now dx:ax contains the 32-bit number of ticks
```

But this code has a bug.  If by chance the timer interrupt should occur between the instructions marked `BUG`, the main code will get the low and high words of `ticks` out of sync.  Suppose for instance that the value of `ticks` is `0x1234ffff`.  The main code loads the low word, `0xffff`, into ax.  Then the timer interrupt occurs and increments `ticks`, so that it is now `0x12350000`.  The interrupt handler returns and the main code does `mov dx, [ticks+2]`, getting the value `0x1235`.  So now the main code has loaded the value `0x1235ffff`, which is very wrong: it is an entire hour later than the actual time.

We could fix this by using `cli/sti` to disable interrupts, so that an interrupt cannot occur at the site labeled `BUG`.  Corrected code would look like:

```
main_code:
    cli
    mov ax, [ticks]
    mov dx, [ticks+2]
    sti
```

In the particular case of a 32-bit counter, there happen to be other ways to fix this issue without disabling interrupts, but you get the idea.  You can imagine some more complex data structure that both the handler and the main code might need to use: an I/O buffer, some larger struct with information about an I/O event that just occurred, a linked list, etc.

---

The CPU's registers are also a shared resource, such as the SS:SP example that you noticed.  Suppose the stack is currently at `1234:5678` and the main code wants to switch it to `2222:4444`.  You would think to do:

```
switch_stack:
    mov ax, 0x2222
    mov ss, ax
    ;;; BUG: what if interrupt occurs here?
    mov sp, 0x4444
```

If an interrupt were to occur at line `BUG`, the value of SS:SP would be `2222:5678`, and this is where the CPU would push the CS/IP/FLAGS values before jumping to the handler.  This would be really bad, since that isn't the correct location of either the old or the new stack.  There might be important data at that address, which the CPU is now overwriting, and so we are now going to have a hard-to-reproduce memory corruption bug on our hands.

So we would likewise think to fix it with

```
switch_stack:
    mov ax, 0x2222
    cli
    mov ss, ax
    ;;; interrupt can't occur here!
    mov sp, 0x4444
    sti
```

Now it so happens that this is actually a special case.  Since this is a situation where forgetting to disable interrupts would be particularly nasty, the 8086 designers decided to do a little favor for programmers.  The `mov ss, reg` instruction has a very special feature where it will automatically disable interrupts for one instruction.  So in fact, if you code `mov ss, ax` followed **immediately** by `mov sp, 0x2222`, an interrupt cannot occur between then, and the code is actually safe without `cli/sti`.

But let me emphasize again that this is a **unique special case**.  I believe it is only `mov ss, reg` and `pop ss` that have such functionality, so examples like the 32-bit ticks counter really do need `cli/sti`.  And in fact, if you had reversed the two instructions and coded `mov sp, 0x2222` followed by `mov ss, ax` (which on its face would appear just as good), you would again have a bug, and the interrupt handler could be called with the stack pointing to `1234:2222`.  Also, as @ecm noted in a comment, [some early 8086/8088 chips](https://books.google.ca/books?id=1L7PVOhfUIoC&pg=PA492&lpg=PA492&dq=defective%208088%20ss&source=bl&ots=zkBNXaMt1l&sig=ACfU3U2AUbHacKU7bUd82_b3ORmcSji5HQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdkqKp1aHkAhUCJDQIHXFmDakQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=defective%208088%20ss&f=false) had a hardware bug (?) where the "disable interrupts for one instruction" feature didn't work, so on such chips you would also have to use `cli/sti`.  (Or maybe this feature was not actually part of the spec until later?)

The 386 added an `lss` instruction to load both the stack segment and stack pointer in a single instruction, which was a more robust way to address this issue.  It was also more important in that case because in virtual 8086 mode, `cli/sti` would not execute directly but instead would trap to the operating system, which was very slow and best to avoid if possible.

---

You suggest that maybe this has such low probability that we wouldn't really need to worry about it.  Let's look at our 32-bit timer example and imagine an application with an "alarm clock" feature.  While doing other work, it periodically checks the ticks counter, let's say about 100 times per second, to see if a specified time has passed, and if so, it does something to alert the user.  If you leave out the `cli/sti`, then if an interrupt occurs there with the low word equal to `0xffff` (which happens once per hour), it will think the time is one hour later than it is, and so may issue an alert up to one hour too soon.  (If you want to be more dramatic, replace "issue an alert" with "activate dangerous machinery", "fire missiles", etc.)

The `mov ax, mem` instruction on the 8086 took 10 clock cycles, so there are 1000 clock cycles per second when we are vulnerable.  The original IBM PC was clocked at 4.7 MHz, so we have about a 1/4700 chance at the top of every hour of the bug triggering.  If you ship your application to 50,000 users, and each of them uses it for 8 hours per day, then with a little math, you can work out that you can expect to receive 425 complaints about this bug within the first week of release.  Your boss is going to be pretty mad.

And remember, we are back in the mid-1980s and there is no Internet, so you're going to have to mail every one of your 50,000 customers a floppy disk with the patch.  At the cost of a couple dollars plus postage, this bug has cost the company about $100,000.  In contrast, your salary as an entry-level programmer in 1984 is about $20,000 per year.  How do you like your odds of keeping your job?

Comment: The ticks are actually *almost* exactly 64 kilo binary (65_536) ticks per hour, not exactly. In a day there's 18_00B0h or (on some ROM-BIOSes) 18_00B1h ticks, so every hour has a few more ticks than you claim. It's by no means a bad approximation but yeah. And the comment on the early CPU bug was by me, not Peter Cordes. And `lds` as well as `les` existed all the way down to the 8086, just `lss` was missing. And actually using `les` you can do a 32-bit load of arbitrary data from an arbitrary memory location; as you stated "there happen to be other ways to fix this issue" re the tick load.

Comment: @ecm: Is the tick rate exactly 18.2 Hz, not 65536 / 3600 Hz = ~18.20444... Hz?  If so, then 65520 ticks per hour, wrap-around every 1 hour and 0.879 seconds.  Interesting.

Comment: @PeterCordes No, it isn't exactly 18.2 Hz. It is a little higher than even 18.204 Hz. I have a few constants in https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/lclock/file/9595da8fe582/resident.asm#l95 which are all based on 18_00B0h ticks per day (86_400 seconds). This says 65_543.333 ticks per hour, 18.206 per hour (to three digits after the decimal point). However, some implementations of the ROM-BIOS handlers increase the day ticks by one more tick, refer to https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25877/why-did-some-bioses-have-the-timer-tick-wrap-around-at-1800b1h-instead-of-at-180

Comment: @PeterCordes I believe the exact frequency was chosen to be driven by the same IBM PC clock as some sort of NTSC video thingy. The PIT defaults to a 16-bit divisor of 0 (acting as 64 kilo binary divisor) so nearly but not exactly 4 giga binary PIT ticks per hour. "The Intel 8253 PIT was the original timing device used on IBM PC compatibles. It used a 1.193182 MHz clock signal (one third of the color burst frequency used by NTSC, one twelfth of the system clock crystal oscillator,[1] therefore one quarter of the 4.77 MHz CPU clock)" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_interval_timer

Comment: Bug in my earlier comment: "18.206 per hour" should read "per second".

Comment: More information on the details of the PIT at https://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer

Comment: @ecm: Sorry about the misattribution - I guess it's that you two have similar writing styles :)